# Is it possible to update row depending on a time field in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table rooms and another table reservation with datetime in - datetime out of the room. Is it possible to have a column in the table rooms with a boolean that shows reserved. How can I update the row in the table rooms depending on the date and time.

This will help me by not make a join each time I need to load the list of rooms and I can show the room is reserved.

Table Rooms:

- Id (int)
- Name (nvarchar(50))
- IsReserved (bit)

Table Reservations:

- Id(int)
- ReservedBy(int)
- ReservedTo(int)
- ReservedFrom(datetime)
- ReservedTo(datetime)
- RoomId(int) (FK)

Comment: Can you show us some sample table data, as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Do you mean "reserved just now", or "reserved now or later"?

Comment: A room can have multiple reservations that have time from to time to but I just want to minimize the join to multiple tables.

Comment: I want the the boolean IsReserved(bit) in table rooms changes depending on the value of the table reservations. The only possible way I know of is to run a sql agent job every day but it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @gotqn any hints how I can do it, i updated the question.

Comment: You could do it with a computed column

Comment: @LonelyThinker Why you want to skip the join? Is it slow?

Comment: @gotqn well not really but people suggested me to not have many joins, the computed column seems to going to have a worst performance than a join.

Comment: You are embarking on what is known as premature optimization. That is the decision to make non-standard design choices in response to a performance problem that doesn't exist. It is also the root of all evil. Just join the two tables and be done with it. If there is a performance problem then some basic indexing will solve it easily.

Comment: @ Sean Lange Ok thanks, I will take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user-defined function, which should look if the room is reserved or not. This function could take as an input the room id and could return 0, when the room is not booked and 1 when is booked. If we call this function `CheckRoomAvailability`, drop the already defined column and declare it as a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE Rooms
ADD IsReserved AS dbo.CheckRoomAvailability(Id)
```

each time you read from this table, you should see also if it is available or not.

The user defined function I mentioned before, it could be created as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckRoomAvailability(@RoomId INT)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    BIT @IsAvailable = 0;

    DATETIME @Now = GETDATE(); // Probably here you need GETUTCDATE(), don't know, if you have chosen or not UTC...

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM 
                  Reservations 
              WHERE 
                  RoomId = @RoomId 
              AND @Now BETWEEN ReservedFrom AND ReservedTo
    )
    BEGIN
        SET @IsAvailable = 1;
    END

    RETURN @IsAvailable;
END
```